# Exporting PDF format from Power BI embedded with report filters

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, export-to-pdf

We have successfully created the C # code to export PDF format reports from Power BI embedded however the report does not have the applied filters with the export. Help on this will be much appreciated.. See sample querystring for our filters below

```
queryString = "Community Attribute/Community Name and ID in ('Bella Vista Apartment Homes (1909)') AND Community Attribute/Community Status in ('Active','Active - Single Family Homes','Active - BTR') AND User Community Access/Email in ('email@example.com')";
```

Comment: Sharing your query-string (...and your e-mail address) doesn't really tell us anything about how you're doing your PDF export...

Comment: The implication is your "C# code" is exporting  the "input" and not the "output" from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting report to pdf with filters using query String parameter won't work.

Refer [Export To File](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#filters) to export the Power BI embedded report with filters applied.

Need to additionally pass the filters in Request Body. Refer [Export To File REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#powerbireportexportconfiguration)

```
{
    format: 'pdf',
    powerBIReportConfiguration: {
       pages: [{ pageName: 'ReportSection3' }],    
       reportLevelFilters: [{
             filter: "Store/Territory eq 'NC'"
        }]
}
```